# Text file change inheritance, is it possible?

Tags: inheritance, text, organization

Let's say I have received a text file that describes how to service a car.

Currently the text file has all steps for every type of car in line:

I.E:

## Service_Cars.txt

```
Step 1: Open Hood
Step 2: Check Fluids
Step 3: Fill gas tank (NA FOR ELECTRIC CARS)
Step 4: Charge car (NA FOR GAS CARS)
```

etc

I want to split this text file into multiple files, one for each type of car.

## Service_Gas_Car.txt

```
Step 1: Open Hood
Step 2: Check Fluids
Step 3: Fill gas tank (NA FOR ELECTRIC CARS)
//Step 4: Charge car (NA FOR GAS CARS)
```

## Service_Electric_Car.txt

```
Step 1: Open Hood
Step 2: Check Fluids
//Step 3: Fill gas tank (NA FOR ELECTRIC CARS)
Step 4: Charge car (NA FOR GAS CARS)
```

However, I want them to still be related to the original text file.
If the original "Service_Cars" directions change, I want each of my new text files to be updated.

I know that splitting the text files like this with one master file isn't the best way to do this, but lets say a mechanic already has this list, and wants to make the above changes, for organization purposes.

Is there a good tool that exists for something like this? So far the best idea I've came up with is to write a program that takes the "Master" file, scans for "NA FOR _", and generates the other text files. However, I want a non-programmer to be able to update the text files, so I was hoping for a more "natural" solution.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful some UML tool, this could be modeled as an activity diagram. I've used an online free tool ([draw.io](https://www.draw.io)) to make a very simple diagram:

[image: Activity diagram]

Besides, most UML tools exports to XML. You can parse it and use it to generate your .txt files or any other format.

Comment: I agree that UML would be a good tool for me if I was starting from scratch. The problem is these text files already exist, and I'm tasked with using them as my base "Master" files.

Comment: Ok, I see then. So you have a legacy problem with plain text files which look like pseudocode with line numbers (like in some old Basic nightmare). And you have to use some defensive programming because there are some non-savvy tech people (i.e. mechanics)... This looks like fun!. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: That is exactly what's going on :(

No problem! 

For now i'm just sticking to writing a GUI application that takes the text file, parses it (looking for NA flags), and then generating the other files. 

That way the operator can still edit the "Master" file, but have nice new text files to use elsewhere. 

(I'd still greatly appreciate a better way to do this haha)

Thanks a lot for the attempt!